# How to simplify this equation: $1\cdot N + 2(N-1) + 3(N -2) + \cdots + i(N - i + 1) + \dots + N \cdot1$?

Tags: summation

$$1 (N) + 2(N-1) + 3(N -2) + \cdots + i(N - i + 1) + \cdots + N (1)  $$

I need to write it in simplest form?

here 1(N) means 1 multiply by N

Comment: Sorry, but does $N$ stand for a complex number?

Comment: Babak, $N$ must be a natural number; $i$ is intended as an index, not the square root of $-1$.  So the sum is $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (1+k)(N-k)$.

(Ah, now I see why you asked that.  Grijesh, the tags you've chosen are completely inappropriate.)

Comment: I am tiring to answer some other problem  related to computer scince

Comment: Apart from [the post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113556/how-to-show-that-sum-k-1n-kn1-k-binomn23) already mentioned by Normal Human, some other posts which are [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1113556) might be interesting for you, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^Nk(N-k+1)=\sum_{k=1}^N kN-\sum_{k=1}^Nk^2+\sum_{k=1}^Nk=N\,\frac{N(N+1)}2-\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}6+\frac{N(N+1)}2=\frac{N(N+1)}2\left(N-\frac{2N+1}3+1\right)=\frac{N(N+1)(N+2)}6.
$$

Comment: There is a typo. It should be N+2 in place of N+4.

Comment: @Gautam Shenoy - thanks , Martin Argerami - thanks!

Comment: @draks 10/6 = 1 floor function

Comment: how are you expanding $\sum_{k=1}^N kN$ to $N\,\frac{N(N+1)}2$ ?

Comment: It's the basic identity $\sum_{k=1}^Nk=\frac{N(N+1)}2$, multiplied by $N$.

Answer (score 4):

Your sum can be written as

$$\sum_{k=1}^Nk(N-k+1) = N\sum_{k=1}^{N}k - \sum_{k=1}^N{k^2} + \sum_{k=1}^N{k}$$

$$ = \frac{N(N+1)^2}{2} - \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 3):

A more complex but fun alternative solution using Finite Calculus:

$$
  \begin{align}
  　\sum_{x=1}^N x \left[(N+1)-x\right]
    & = \sum_{1}^{N+1} \left[ Nx - x(x-1)\right] \delta x
      = \sum_{1}^{N+1} \left( Nx^{(1)} - x^{(2)} \right) \delta x \\
    & = \left[ \frac{N}{2}x^{(2)} - \frac{1}{3} x^{(3)} \right]_{1}^{N+1}
      = \left[ \frac{N}{2}x(x-1) - \frac{1}{3} x(x-1)(x-2) \right]_{1}^{N+1}\\
    & = \left[ \frac{N^2(N+1)}{2} - 0 \right] - \left[ \frac{1}{3}(N+1)N(N-1) - 0 \right] \\
    & = \frac{N(N+1)(N+2)}{6}.
  \end{align}
$$

Comment: @ffrenz : Thanks frenz!!