# How to simplify summation $(1\cdot2) + (2\cdot3) + (3\cdot4) + (4\cdot5) + (5\cdot6) + ... + (N\cdot(N+1))$ in terms of N?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have function f(n) like:

```
 N=1   result = 2
 N=2   result = 8
 N=3   result = 20
 N=4   result = 40
 N=5   result = 70
 N=6   result = 112
 N=7   result = 168
 N=8   result = 240
 N=9   result = 330
 N=10  result = 440
```

I could understand that its something like:

```
N = 1,   (1 + 1) = 2

N = 2,   (1 + 1) + (3 + 3) = 8

N = 3,   (1 + 1) + (3 + 3) + (4 + 4 + 4)= 20

N = 4,   (1 + 1) + (3 + 3) + (4 + 4 + 4) + (5 + 5 + 5 + 5)  =  40

N = 5,   (1 + 1) + (3 + 3) + (4 + 4 + 4) + (5 + 5 + 5 + 5) + (6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6) = 70

N = 6,   (1 + 1) + (3 + 3) + (4 + 4 + 4) + (5 + 5 + 5 + 5) + (6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6) + (7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 7)= 112
```

Finally, I could understood that sum of `N` in three loop is:

[**Question**]

```
(1*2) + (3*2) + (4*3) + (5*4) + (6*5) + ... + (N * (N-1))
```

Now, I wants to simplify this equation in terms of `N`?

A similar kind of question I have asked previously [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247150/how-to-simplify-this-equation) also, If I compare results of both series it looks the result in term of N is = `( ((N) * (N+1) * (N+2)) / 3 )`. but I am not sure.

Can someone help me to simplify this question further.

**Edit:**  After Mr.Mark Bennet's comment I recheck my equation it should be actually following (notice the small change):

```
(1*2) + (2*3) + (3*4) + (4*5) + (5*6) + ... + (N * (N+1))
```

Comment: I am tiring to answer some other problem related to computer science (I am from computer so its hard to solve me I was trying since an hours). **Can someone also improve my tags**

Comment: You might do better to write the series as: $(1+1)+(2+2+2)+(3+3+3+3)+(4+4+4+4+4)+\dots$ so that all the terms are in the same form.

Comment: @Mark Why not make the first term one $2$ instead? That saves a lot of effort.

Comment: @MarkBennet `6` is absent in series

Comment: @MarkBennet Got it Thanks!!, But I am sure for my final sequence `(1*2) + (3*2) + (4*3) + (5*4) + (6*5) + ... + (N * (N-1))`

Comment: @Lord_Farin - I did it so the number $1$ was visible in the first term. Of course your suggestion is more efficient.

Comment: $2\times 1+3 \times 2+4\times 3+ 5\times 4 +\dots$ to put all the terms in the same form ...

Comment: @MarkBennet Please check my answer

Comment: This post is about very similar sum: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707256/how-to-show-sum-i-1n-binomi2-binomn13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the comment, your sum is:
$$
\sum_{1 \le k \le n} k (k + 1)
  = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k^2 + \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k
  = \frac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}{6} + \frac{n (n + 1)}{2}
  = \frac{n (n + 1) (n + 2)}{3}
$$
Or even simpler, with $k^{\overline{m}} = k (k + 1) \ldots (k + m - 1)$, you have
$$
\sum_{1 \le k \le n} k^{\overline{m}}
  = \frac{n^{\overline{m + 1}}}{m + 1}
$$
In your case $m = 2$.

Comment: do you means  `(1*2) + (3*2) + (4*3) + (5*4) + (6*5) + ... + (N * (N-1))`  **?** by *`last description`*

Comment: Hi please read **Edit part** its actually: `(1*2) + (3*2) + (4*3) + (5*4) + (6*5) + ... + (N * (N+1))` Sorry I mistake I made

Comment: Please check my answer ..

Comment: ok So you updated your answer.. its correct na Thanks a lot vonbrand!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Mr.Vonbrand and Mr.Martin Argerami (my previous answer I linked), I could write the simplified question for my edited series:

```
    (1*2) + (2*3) + (3*4) + (4*5) + (5*6) + ... + (n * (n+1))
```

Solution:

$$
\sum_{1 \le k \le n} k (k + 1)
  = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k^2 + \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k
  = \frac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}{6} + \frac{n (n + 1)}{2}
  = \frac{n (n + 1)}{2} (\frac{(2n + 1)}{3} + 1) 
  = \frac{n (n + 1)}{2} (\frac{(2n + 4)}{3} ) 
  = \frac{n(n+1)2(n+2)}6.
  = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}3. 
$$

Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: What I am trying to explain is that some of your terms have the higher number first, and some the lower number (1*2, 3*2, 4*3, N*(N+1)). It would help in organising your work, and in recognising patterns, if the terms were all written the same way.

Comment: @MarkBennet Got it!..done thanks :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Not to mention that $n$ suddenly becomes $N$ for no reason...

Comment: @ByronSchmuland oh! this because I partially copied from [linked question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247150/how-to-simplify-this-equation?lq=1), Now corrected. Thanks :)