# How to show $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{i}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

> *Show that* $\,\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{i}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3}$.

I'm thinking right now (though not getting anywhere with it) that I want to expand out the summation portion to $i!/2!(i-2)!$ and simplify from there? Not sure if that will help, not to mention if I put $1$ in for $i$ I get $1/-2$ which I don't think is right.

Anyone care to shed some light on the subject?

Thanks.

Comment: It's actually from $i=2$ and here, proved it: https://ideone.com/Tq36eW (n > 0 apparently).

Comment: as i commented on the top answer below, the problem i am trying to solve is i=1, not i=2, thanks

Comment: @user3216655 The other users answered the question you wrote in the original title, but it seems that you want to know how to calculate $\binom{1}{2}$. I changed your title and gave an explanation below.

Comment: $\binom{n}{m}=0$ if $m>n$. This is true both combinatorially (a set of size $n$ has no subsets of size $m>n$) and algebraically using the polynomial definition $n(n-1)\cdots(n-n)\cdots(n-m+1)/m!=0$.

Answer (score 11):

What we shall show is that
$$
\sum_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3},
$$
using a combinatorial argument:

The right-hand side is the number of the ways to choose three numbers among $\{1,2,\ldots,n,n+1\}$.

This is equal to the sum of $P_i$'s, $i=2,\ldots,n$, where $P_i$ is the number of ways to choose three numbers among  $\{1,2,\ldots,n,n+1\}$ with the largest one being $i+1$.
 But $P_i$ is the number of ways to choose two numbers among $\{1,2,\ldots,i\}$, which is equal to $\binom{i}{2}$. Hence
$$
\binom{n+1}{3}=\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}.
$$

Comment: that's not what i want to show, although i appreciate the answer. the question, as per the text is i=1, i appreciate the answer but the problem i'm having is dealing with it being i=1 (i understand it with i=2, not with 1) thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user3216655, this shows that the original question is wrong (typo?).

Comment: @vonbrand the original question is not wrong, all i'm saying is the first couple people answered the wrong question, i=1 in my question, but others answered the right question below

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to be about how to calculate $\binom{1}{2}$. In general, for $n,k \geq 0$, the binomial coefficient can be defined to be the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$. In other words, $\binom{1}{2}$ is the coefficient of $x^2$ in $(1+x)^1$. But this coefficient is 0. Hence $\binom{1}{2} = 0$, which is why this doesn't affect the validity of the proofs in the other answers.

As another way to think about it, $\binom{1}{2}$ counts the number of ways to choose $2$ objects from a set of $1$; there are no such ways. In general, $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ for $k > n \geq 0$.

Comment: Or: $\binom{i}{2}=i(i-1)/2$, which is $0$ when $i=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $n-1 =2k$ $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{i}{2} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i\cdot (i-1)}{2}=\frac{1\cdot 0}{2}+\frac{2\cdot 1}{2}+\frac{3\cdot 2}{2}+\frac{4\cdot 3}{2} + \ldots +\frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{2} = \frac{2\cdot 1+3\cdot 2+4\cdot 3+ \ldots +n\cdot (n-1)}{2} = \frac{2^2\cdot2+4^2\cdot2+6^2\cdot2+\ldots +(n-1)^2\cdot2}{2}=2^2+4^2+6^2+\ldots+(n -1)^2=4(1+2^2+3^2+\ldots+k^2)=\frac{4k\cdot(k+1)\cdot(2k+1)}{6}=\frac{4\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\frac{n+1}{2}\cdot n}{6} = \frac{(n+1)\cdot n\cdot(n-1)}{3!}=\binom{n+1}{3}$$
Similarly if $n-1 =2k +1$ you have $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{i}{2} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i\cdot (i-1)}{2}=\frac{1\cdot 0}{2}+\frac{2\cdot 1}{2}+\frac{3\cdot 2}{2}+\frac{4\cdot 3}{2} + \ldots +\frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{2} = \frac{2\cdot 1+3\cdot 2+4\cdot 3+ \ldots +n\cdot (n-1)}{2} = \frac{2^2\cdot2+4^2\cdot2+6^2\cdot2+\ldots +(n-2)^2\cdot2+n\cdot(n-1)}{2}=2^2+4^2+6^2+\ldots+(n-2)^2+n\cdot (n-1)=4(1+2^2+3^2+4^2+\ldots+(n-2)^2)+\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}=\frac{4k\cdot(k+1)\cdot(2k+1)}{6}+\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}=\frac{4\frac{n-2}{2}\cdot\frac{n}{2}\cdot (n-1)}{6}+\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}=\frac{(n-2)\cdot n\cdot(n-1)}{3!}+\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)+3n\cdot(n-1)}{3!}=\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2+3)}{3!}=\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n+1)}{3!}=\binom{n+1}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  The basic Pascal's triangle identity is
$$\binom{i+1}{k}=\binom{i}{k}+\binom{i}{k-1}\ .$$
Taking $k=3$ and rearranging,
$$\binom{i}{2}=\binom{i+1}{3}-\binom{i}{3}\ .$$
Therefore the sum is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left[\binom{i+1}{3}-\binom{i}{3}\right]\ ,$$
which is a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2}=\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}$$

Since $\binom22=\binom33$

$$\sum_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2}=\binom{3}{3}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}$$

Pascal's Triangle Identity states that

$$\binom{n-1}k+\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\binom{n}{k}$$

So,

$$\sum_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2}=\color{red}{\binom{3}{3}+\binom{3}{2}}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}$$

$$\sum_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2}=\color{red}{\binom{4}{3}}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}$$

$$\sum_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2}=\color{green}{\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{2}}+\binom{5}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}$$

$$\sum_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2}=\color{green}{\binom{5}{3}}+\binom{5}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}$$

So on and so forth, until we have

$$\sum_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2}=\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{i \choose 2} = {n + 1 \choose 3}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \choose 2}}&=\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
> \int_{\verts{z}
> = 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{3}}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z^{3}}
> \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{1 + z}^{k}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z^{3}}\,
> {\pars{1 + z}\bracks{\pars{1 +z}^{n} - 1} \over \pars{1 +z} - 1}
> \\[3mm]&=\underbrace{%
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} \over z^{4}}}
> _{\ds{=\ {n + 1 \choose 3}}}\
> -\
> \overbrace{\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 + z \over z^{4}}}
> ^{\ds{=\ 0}}
> =\color{#00f}{\large{n + 1 \choose 3}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The process of choosing all combinations of three from $n+1$ can be thought about like this:

If we define $e_i$ to be the ith element,

1. Choose $e_1$ and then choose 2 other elements from the rest. These would be all combinations that have $e_1$ as a choice.
2. Choose $e_2$ as an element and then choose 2 other elements from the n-1 after $e_2$. These would be all combinations that have $e_2$ as a choice, but not $e_1$, as it  was already counted.
3. Choose $e_3$ as an element and then choose 2 others from the n-2 after $e_3$. These would be all combinations that have $e_3$ as a choice, excluding $e_1$ and $e_2$ since they were already counted.

...